# Lifetime error using remaining accounts and magicblock session token macro

Tags: anchor, magicblock, session-token, remaining-accounts

I am facing an error when using lifetimes with magicblock's `session_auth_or` macro in my instruction

Here is a sample of the instructions

```
#[session_auth_or(
    ctx.accounts.protocol_state.admin_address == ctx.accounts.admin.key(),
    ErrorCode::PublicKeyMismatch
)]
pub fn my_custom_instruction<'key, 'accounts, 'remaining, 'info>(
    ctx: Context<'key, 'accounts, 'remaining, 'info, CustomAccounts<'info>>
) -> Result<()> {
```

This is the error I am facing

```
use of undeclared lifetime name `'accounts`
undeclared lifetimerustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
expire_usage.rs(94, 27): consider introducing lifetime `'accounts` here: `<'accounts>`
```